# Can a view field length prevent CREATE VIEW

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm working in a sandbox with many many views. The views that concern me, of which there are about 10, are half way down a list on my left handside in my SQL client, which is Teradata.

I wanted to create a "dummy" view that I could use to quickly find my views by eye balling on the left hand side.

I just cut n paste the query for a previous view I had created but changed the name:

```
CREATE VIEW  RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIM00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 AS
SELECT VwNIMEventFct.NIM_USER_ID, COUNT(VwNIMEventFct.NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID) AS DownloadCount
FROM RDMAVWSANDBOX.VwNIMEventFct
WHERE NIM_EVENT_TYPE_ID = 884
GROUP BY NIM_USER_ID
```

All those zeros are intentional, I want this table to stick out when I'm scrolling down the views.

But it does not create the view. I tried it with three 0's and it does.

Why!? Can I adjust settings somewhere? It seems Teradata will not allow me to create this view and it appears as though it's to do with the name being too long.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I don't see any error. The view just does not appear in my views list like it normally does

Comment: Then maybe your tool just doesn't show it? Can you see an entry in the Teradata system views?

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to check that @a_horse_with_no_name. I can see the view turn up when I give it a shorter name though

Comment: Found the problem. On the bottom left hand corner on the SQL client a small message pops up - the view name cannot be longer than 30 characters.

Comment: Any database/table/column name in Teradata is restricted to 30 characters. Only the latest release TD14.10 supports 128 chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Teradata has a 30 character Limit for field names unless version TD14.10 or above. Thanks @dnoeth for the info